# Raspberry pi + Ubuntu Mate 16.04 + RealVNC

Tags: vnc, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on my raspberry pi 3. I downloaded the RealVNC Server deb from their website and installed it. I remember in Raspbian there was an icon to click and log into my account. I dont know how to log into my account in mate. And in their website, they said to switch to xfce4, for it to work. Have anyone tried it with Mate? How did it came out?